# C++ sending reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

let's suppose I have:

```
template<class S, class T>
class node
{
public:
  S key;

  node(const S& key)
    : key(key)
  {}
};
```

Will this save a new instance of `key` or simply point to the one sent as parameter to the function?

I'm quit not sure since on the one hand I am sending a reference "kind of a pointer", on the other hand key isn't a pointer so a new instance should be made...

Comment: In `key(key)` it will copy `key` to `this->key`.

Comment: The type of the member variable tells the whole truth.

Comment: implementation wise a reference is kind of a pointer. However, for what a reference is imho it rather helps to understand that a reference is a reference and a pointer is a pointer. They are not the same

Comment: If you're unsure, write a class that prints something from constructor, copy constructor, move constructor etc. and _see_ what happens. But yes, `S key` is an object and must be copy-constructed from the reference parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To be asolutely certain, look at the adresses of the objects. Different objects have different adresses and the same object has the same adress.

```
template<class S, class T>
class node
{
public:
  S key;

  node(const S& key)
    : key(key)
  {}
};
    
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    node<int,int> n(x);
    std::cout << &x << "\n";
    std::cout << &(n.key) << "\n";
}
```

Possible output :

```
0x7ffec1abb16c
0x7ffec1abb168
```

A reference is just an alias for a different object. Your member `key` on the other hand is an object of type `S` (not a reference), hence it cannot be the same object as the one the parameter to the constructor refers to. In the above example, the member is initialized with the value of `x`.

Comment: 463035818 isn't even a prime number

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili its a little funny that nobody complained about the first part of the name so far :P

Comment: Well, it feels a bit silly to say something like "2^19937 - 1 is a larger prime" when 463035818 isn't even a prime number to begin with. That maybe why no one complains about the first part :D

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili hm ok, maybe its only the second largest. Off by one can happen

Answer (score 1):

The code is perfectly sane, but using `key` twice makes it harder to describe what happens. So, small modification for the sake of discussion:

```
template<class S, class T>
class node {
public:
    S m_key;

node(const S &key) : m_key(key){}
};
```

`key` (the argument) is a reference. That means that the `S` object used as an argument is not copied to key. However, `m_key` (the member) is not a reference. `m_key` must be initialized by the `node` constructor. To do this, the `S` object referenced by `key` is copied to `m_key`.

There could be exceptions to this, if `S` is a bit unusual type. For instance, `S` could be a reference type itself: `node<const int&, void>`.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the parameter `key` is being copied into `this->key`. Therefore, they are not the same object, but 2 identical objects, in different memory locations. If you'd like them to be the same object, I recommend using pointers in this scenario, like this:

```cpp
template<class S, class T>
class node
{
public:
  S *key;

  node(const S& key)
    : key(&key)
  {}
};
```

Comment: "but 2 identical objects" i'd rather say "two objects with equal value", because identity usually refers to one and the same object, while after `a = b;` the expectation is that `a == b`